# I'm trying to put a <button> inside an <input type="radio">'s <label>

Tags: html, css

Edit: The original answer did not work for mobile devices. Go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59454248/im-trying-to-put-a-button-inside-an-input-type-radio-s-label-for-mobile) for a solution that does.

I already know how to make an `<input type="radio">`'s `<label>` look like the button of any specific browser's default `<button>` by playing with the CSS until it looks identical to the `<button>` I'm trying to replicate. But this will look out of place whenever someone views it from a browser that has a different default `<button>`. (Even if I could replicate every default `<button>` for every browser, a new one will probably be invented tomorrow.)

Therefore, I want to use an actual button to get the default styling appropriate to the browser.

A recreation of the code so far:

```html
<h1>Choose A or B</h1>
<label><button type="button"><input type="radio" name="choice" value="A">A</button></label>
<label><button type="button"><input type="radio" name="choice" value="B">B</button></label>
```

Later I'll change `<input type="radio" name="choice" value="A">` to `<input type="radio" name="choice" value="A" hidden>` and use some other styling to show if it's checked or not, but for now I'm leaving it in for diagnostic reasons.

If you run the snippet, you'll notice that clicking the `<input type="radio">` works as intended, but clicking the `<button>`itself does nothing.

Here is another failed attempt:

```html
<h1>Choose A or B</h1>
<input type="radio" name="choice" value="A" id="a"><label for="a"><button type="button">A</button></label>
<input type="radio" name="choice" value="B" id="b"><label for="b"><button type="button">B</button></label>
```

I even tried adding the `disabled` attribute. Nothing is working as intended. Should I give up and style the `<label>` manually, or is there a way to access `<button>`'s default appearance anyway?

(Yes, I already know I could use javascript to simulate `<input type="radio">`'s behaviour on a `<button>` but I'm going to have lots of buttons in lots of groups throughout the website. So I'll just style `<label>` manually if it means the website will be easier to maintain. Likewise for installing an entire library just for this one problem.)

Comment: I guess you aren't allowed to nest interactive elements that why you get this issue. You will get errors in the validator: https://validator.w3.org/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An idea is to add `pointer-events:none;` to the button but you won't have the styles of the `:focus`,`:active` and `:hover` state.

```css
button {
  pointer-events:none;
}
```

```html
<h1>Choose A or B</h1>
<input type="radio" name="choice" value="A" id="a"><label for="a"><button type="button">A</button></label>
<input type="radio" name="choice" value="B" id="b"><label for="b"><button type="button">B</button></label>
```

You can, however, add your own custom `:focus` `:active` `:hover` and `:checked` state with:

```
input[type="radio"]:focus + label button{
    /*add checked style here*/
label:hover > button {
    /*add hover style here*/
}
label:active > button {
    /*add active style here*/
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + label button{
    /*add checked style here*/
```

Comment: Note, this fix only works for the second snippet. It does nothing for the first one. (Learned the hard way.)

Comment: @JonathonPhilipChambers because the first one is an invalid HTML to start with (like I comment above)

Comment: I thought you were saying BOTH snippets were invalid.

Comment: That markup's invalid. As the validator puts it: "Any button descendant of a label element with a for attribute must have an ID value that matches that for".

Comment: @JonathonPhilipChambers yes both seems to be invalid as @ Alohci pointed. If you add the ID you will have the same ID twice which is invalid too but the first one is more critical since you are nesting interactive element

Answer (score 1):

It will not work, as you are doing. You need to do it like this.

```css
[type="radio"]:checked,
[type="radio"]:not(:checked) {
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px;
}
[type="radio"]:checked + label,
[type="radio"]:not(:checked) + label
{
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 28px;
    cursor: pointer;
    line-height: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #666;
}
[type="radio"]:checked + label:before,
[type="radio"]:not(:checked) + label:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: #fff;
    z-index: -1;
}
[type="radio"]:checked + label:after,
[type="radio"]:not(:checked) + label:after {
    content: '';
    width: 94px;
    height: 24px;
    background: #F87DA9;
    position: absolute;
    top: 4px;
    left: 4px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
    z-index: -1;
}
[type="radio"]:not(:checked) + label:after {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    transform: scale(0);
}
[type="radio"]:checked + label:after {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<form action="#">
  <p>
    <input type="radio" id="test1" name="radio-group" checked>
    <label for="test1">Apple</label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="radio" id="test2" name="radio-group">
    <label for="test2">Peach</label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="radio" id="test3" name="radio-group">
    <label for="test3">Orange</label>
  </p>
</form>
```

You can do it using CSS `:before` and `:after` pseudo-classes without using any button.  You can modify the above example as per your requirements.

Code is copied from https://codepen.io/manabox/pen/raQmpL and is used after modifications in the above example.

Comment: mostly copied for here: https://codepen.io/manabox/pen/raQmpL and doesn't really answer the question

Comment: More specifically, the buttons only work if you click the text. I already know how to do that. But I want the entire button to be clickable. (If this answer allowed for that, it would at least get my upvote)

Comment: @JonathonPhilipChambers you will need to do minor CSS adjustments to do your job.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Yes its copied from there. Aim is to help others with what ever we have.

Comment: *Aim is to help others with what ever we have* --> you need to give proper attribution and credit to the original author and not simply make it like it's your code. Would you like someone to pick your work and use it as his own? I don't think so.

Comment: @OptimumCreative see correct answer for tweaks required.

You just took my not-working example, and googled a similar not working example.

I'm not even convinced you understood the question or what "default button style" means.

Comment: @TemaniAfif I have added attribution as well. See the last line