# I'm trying to put a <button> inside an <input type=“radio”>'s <label> for mobile

Tags: javascript, html, mobile

I asked this question a month ago: [I'm trying to put a <button> inside an <input type="radio">'s <label>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59047748/im-trying-to-put-a-button-inside-an-input-type-radios-label)

The answer I marked correct worked perfectly... for the desktop browsers I tested. Testing on my iPhone 6, both Safari and Chrome have the buttons unclickable.

Correct answer snippet copied below:

```css
button {
  pointer-events:none;
}
```

```html
<h1>Choose A or B</h1>
<input type="radio" name="choice" value="A" id="a"><label for="a"><button type="button">A</button></label>
<input type="radio" name="choice" value="B" id="b"><label for="b"><button type="button">B</button></label>
```

Is there a solution that works for both smartphone AND desktop?

I could get rid of `<input type=“radio”>` and rewrite radio button behaviour in JavaScript from scratch, but I'm hoping I won't need to do that. Is there an easier way?

Comment: please show me your now code.

Comment: @seunggabi It was copied directly from the solution. I tried recreating it as a snippet here, but I couldn't get snippets to run AT ALL on my phone. Meanwhile the workstation I'm at right now can only code locally and cannot upload. But if you want to see it in action visit my website www.woolchambers.com.au and click the button that says "fibre"

Comment: @JonathonPhilipChambers upgrade your chrome and safari browsers. According to [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#search=button), there is full support for all elements of the HTML button in versions released in Oct 19; prior to that the support was 'unknown'.

Comment: @RachelGallen both browsers are fully up to date for iPhone 6

Comment: @seunggabi I just copied the correct answer and included it in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<h1>Choose A or B</h1>
<label>
<input type="radio" name="mode" value="create">
<span style="-webkit-appearance: button;">create table</span>
</label>

<label>
<input type="radio" name="mode" value="create">
<span style="-webkit-appearance: button;">create field</span>
</label>
```

Comment: I think this is the correct answer, but how do I run it on my phone? To verify it is correct?

Comment: If you promise you have tested this on an iPhone 6 or earlier and it works, I will mark this as correct.

Comment: why did you use <i> instead of <div> or <span>?

Comment: You can use <div> or <span> too, <i> was placed just in case